# What are some instances in which ashkenazim do NOT follow Rama?

Tags: halacha, ashkenazi, rama

What are some instances in which ashkenazim do *not* follow Rama? I can think of Kapparos off hand, but surely there are more...

Comment: I'm guessing there are at least 1,000. (Assuming you mean "many Ashkenazim" and not "all Ashkenazim".)

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/959/759

Comment: Bameh Madlikin, sitting for Kiddush, Mincha before Plag, bedikos achar tashmish for a woman without a veset, the third parsha break in tefillin, Glat, giving terumah to a kohein, breaking the kos of eirusin, ... I'm sure you could find at least 1 example in every 10 simanim. Why are we listing this again?

Comment: Also: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68886

Comment: Also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78806

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a community-wiki answer for Orach Chayim. Please [edit it](/posts/64722/edit).

Common practice is not like 31:2 in that most do not say a blessing on tefillin on chol hamoed even quietly.

Common practice is not like 53:23: synagogue dues are a set amount per family, but less for those who can't afford, or perhaps some other scheme, but generally not 50% charged per capita and the rest by ability to pay.

Common practice is not like 56:2: many do interrupt and/or pause between the words "hu" and "le'eila".

Common practice is not like 57:1: the leader doesn't take his time saying *Bar'chu*.

Common practice is not like 111:1: the congregation does not respond Amen to the leader's blessing of Gaal Yisrael after Shema.

Common practice is not like 127:1: the congregation doesn't recite all of Modim Derabanan while bowed.

Common practice is not like 127:2: the congregation doesn't conclude Modim Derabanan with "Baruch Attah Adonay Chai HaOlamim".

Nor like 134:1: most don't fast.

Nor like 134:2 "כן": most don't bend their knees.

Common practice is not like 236:2: many do not rise for the 18-verses ("Baruch Hashem LeOlam...") after Shema at Maariv.

Common practice is not like 242:1: to bake bread on Fridays for Shabbat-Challa in order to separate Challa.

Common practice is not like 250:1: to sharpen one's knives on Fridays.

Common practice is not like 256:1: for the Shamash to announce that it is time to get ready for Shabbat, 30-60 minutes before Shabbat.

Common practice is not like 264:2: to put a grain of salt and a bean at the mouth of the lamp to ensure it burns properly.

Common practice is not like 271:12: most Jews today do not wash before Kiddush.

Nor like 429:1: we distribute food and/or money, but not specifically wheat.

Nor like 473:4 as to plate layout.

Comment: Common practice isn't like 31:2? Most non-chassidic Ashkenazim I know recite the beracha aloud on ch"m.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt that too would be unlike the Rema, but I have never been to a shul where the blessing on tefillin is said aloud like birkot hashachar any day of the year.  Obviously if those wearing tefillin say the blessing quietly I won't hear them, but I was told one does not make the Bracha nowadays.  I myself don't wear tefillin on chol hamoed.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen, my family is still noheig to make the beracha on chol hamoed, al pi Minhag Frankfurt, in fact, R' Hamburger paskens that the only time that we should not put on tefillin on ch"m is when we are davening in an Israeli schul where it is not the practice.

Answer (score 5):

This is a community-wiki answer for Yoreh Deah. Please edit it.

Common practice is not like 87:3: even at chicken-main-dish banquets with creamer, the creamer has a notice.

Common practice is not like 89:2: we *do* correct those who don't wait after hard cheese.

Comment: msh Can you source your claims regarding common practice vis-a-vis 89:2?

Comment: @DoubleAA, no. It's my impression. If you disagree and have (equal or) better basis for doing so, please edit it out.