# Are there any cases where Sephardim generally hold by the ReM"A?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, shulchan-aruch, rama

[The ReM"A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Isserles) famously wrote a gloss on the [*Shulchan Arukh*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch) called *HaMapah* where he pointed out places where the *minhagim* of the *Ashkenazim* (which he was familiar with) differed from the *minhagim* which were presented in the *Shulchan Arukh* (which were primarily *Sephardi* in origin). The ReM"A's work is widely considered to be a very important *halakhic* work and nowadays it is included in every publication of the *Shulchan Arukh*<sup>(citation needed)</sup>. *Ashkenazim* follow many of the ReM"A's rulings--even when they contradict the *Shulchan Arukh*.

I am interested in finding out whether nowadays *Sephardim* follow any of the rulings of the ReM"A in places where they contradict the *Shulchan Arukh*. For the purposes of this question, I wish to exclude the following cases:

1. Cases where only a small minority of *Sephardim* follow the ReM"A.  I am only interested in cases where a significant group of *Sephardim* follow him (even if it isn't a majority).
2. Cases where the Sh"A rules leniently and the ReM"A rules stringently and people follow the ReM"A "in order to satisfy all opinions." I am interested instead in cases where *Sephardim* follow the ReM"A because they hold that his position is the *correct* one. (I understand that this is difficult to judge, so I can be flexible with this requirement.)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64719/1713

Comment: I understand that everyone holds like the ReM"A on YD 151:1 who is lenient on *lifnei iver* when you aren't the only provider. However, I don't have any proof right now.

Comment: This is a subjective question. Are we dealing with contemporary Sephardim, or any groups since his time. Many (most?) Moroccan Jews for example traditionally follow the Rema. After moving to Israel, however, many of them are influenced by the Pan-Sephardi movement that developed there under the aegis of Hahkam Ovadiah z"l, that follows the Shulchan Arukh over the Rema.

Comment: I support @mevaqesh . There have been Moroccans who dont eat kitniyot and other seemingly ashkenazic customs. But I think the biggest mistake is to assume Sephardim are uniform in any way.

Comment: @Aaron as I stated in my (now deleted) comment conversation, this question makes no assumption that _Sephardim_ are uniform in any way. That's why I specifically mention that I don't care if it's a majority of _Sephardim_ as long as it's a significant group.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78806