# When do ashkenazim follow the shulchan aruch and not the Rama?

Tags: halacha, ashkenazi, shulchan-aruch

When in halacha do Ashkenazim follow the shulchan aruch and not the Rama and in which aspects ?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68886/1713

Answer (score 1):

There are a few. One which I remember in Hilchos Kiddush Orach Chaim  271,12:

> אחר שקידש על כוס נוטל ידיו ומברך על נטילת ידים ואם נטל ידיו קודם קידוש
>   גלי דעתיה דריפתא חביבא ליה לא יקדש על היין אלא על הפת:
>
> הגה: ויש אומרים דלכתחלה יש ליטול ידיו קודם הקידוש ולקדש על היין (הרא"ש
>   ומרדכי פרק ערבי פסחים ורשב"א והגהות מיימוני פרק כ"ט והטור) וכן המנהג
>   פשוט במדינות אלו

Most Ashkenazim follow the Mechaber and wash after kiddush before hamotzi.

Comment: I edited your post in order to format the quote. For future reference, you can do this by highlighting the text of the quote and clicking on the quotation mark icon right above the text box.

Comment: On a phone no such option is available but thanks anyway @alex for doing so

Comment: Are you using the Stack Exchange app? It has the quotation button.

Comment: If you just preface a paragraph with a `>` it becomes a quotation. Any phone has that capability