# Halacha not like Zohar

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, zohar

Is there a list anywhere of all the places standard orthodox Jews don't rule like Zohar?
Ideally where nobody does like wait time between milk and meat. But if there are places where Chassidim and Yeshivish people don't rule like Zohar and Morden Orthodox do, that would also fulfill this inquiry.

Whenever discussions about Teffilin on chol hamoed come up, invariably someone will say 'well the Zohar was a Tanna and you can't argue on him".

Ignoring the silly nature of that statement for the moment, I would much rather present a list of places we don't rule like Zohar as response.

Does this exist?

Comment: Of course a list of places we do rule like Zohar would be shorter, but that isn't the point.

Comment: `Ideally where nobody does like wait time between milk and meat.` Some people indeed follow the Zohar in this regard, though maybe they all do it as a *chumra* rather than accepting it *mei'ikar hadin*.

Comment: Are you asking about only where theZohar is contradicted by other authoritative sources?

Comment: @Alex No. Standard practice against an explicit Zohar with no opposing opinion is fine too.

Comment: Perhaps https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62361/759 ? Any 'famous' Zohar position is probably famous exactly because certain groups have adopted it. Finding places where widespread Rishonic practice doesn't accord with the Zohar would be much easier.

Comment: Mahari Abuhav thought the Zohar forbids an oleh from reading along with the korei at all. I don’t think there’s anyone who acts that way today, but there are plenty of opinions who interpret the Zohar to permit the oleh to read along quietly.

Comment: @Double I'm not necessarily looking for a famous Zohar opinion.

Comment: @Joel it's probably a similar story in 99% of cases where a straight reading of the Zohar differs from a well established practice. Don't know how the OP wants to count that

Comment: Perhaps standing for Tefillin Shel Yad? Saying two blessings on Tefillin? These only hold for most Ashkenazim.

Comment: Could’ve sworn that we’ve had the converse asked already (where we _do_ pasken like the Zohar). In the meantime I’m voting to close as too broad.

Comment: @DonielF I'm asking for an existing list or seffer. Not for someone to cull everything together. Although that would theoretically be fine too, that is not my intent.

Comment: @Doniel more broad than https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64719/759 ?

Comment: @DoubleAA אין הכי נמי. I just voted to close that one as well, and I see that the parallel question for [Sefardim and the Mechaber](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78806/) was already closed as too broad.